# Safari error, unable to lounch the browser

Tags: java, selenium, safaridriver

I wrote a basic script that runs in Firefox but keeps breaking on Safari, I searched different websites but couldn't find an answer that worked. Please help.

I'm using Safari - Version 8.0 (10600.1.25)
   OS X Yosemite - Version 10.10 (14A389a)
   Selenium - Version 2.46.0
   Eclipse - Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
   Safaridriver - Version 2.45.0

I have installed driver on browser, and enabled the driver manually.
I'm trying to run the script on a local machine.

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;


public class QC {
WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void trail1() {
driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("http://yahoo.com/");
driver.quit();
```

Logs

```
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:51 PM      
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start     
INFO: Server started on port 18465
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:51 PM    
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:51 PM      
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM   
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler$1  
operationComplete
INFO: Connection opened
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM 
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Driver connected in 1398 ms
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM   
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM   
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Closing connection
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM 
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM 
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer 
stop
INFO: Stopping server
Jul 16, 2015 4:07:53 PM   
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
```

Exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not  
start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the  
remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time:  
'2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'Heathers-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.2.2.60',  
os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10',  
java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
at  
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute
(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)at  
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession
(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init> 
(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>
(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>
(SafariDriver.java:58)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>
(SafariDriver.java:42)
at test.QC.trail1(QC.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall
(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.
run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively
(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate
(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild
(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild
(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.
run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.
run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.
runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.
runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.
run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.
main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.
convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.
convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor
.execute(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
... 29 more
```

SafariDriver logs

```
16:17:14.61 [safaridriver.extension] Creating global session...
16:17:14.61 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Registering new tab
16:17:14.61 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Set command tab to  
udprznycqv1n
16:17:14.61 [safaridriver.extension] Creating debug driver...
16:17:14.61 [safaridriver.extension] Waiting for connect command...
16:17:20.36 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Registering new tab
16:17:20.36 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Tab opened: 
2g26bt5u941a
16:17:20.45 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Ignoring open window  
event
16:17:20.45 [safaridriver.extension.TabManager] Deleting entry for   
tab 2g26bt5u941a
16:17:20.62 [safaridriver.extension.Server] [nsg825n5gk7s] Executing 
command: newSession
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I downgraded to Selenium 2.45.0, it runs perfect now.